# Golang when trying to make method concurrent nothing returns

Tags: go

I have a method that returns Json from the database and it works correctly, however when I try to make it concurrent it does not return anything and does not give any errors. For example this is the method working correctly

```
func Listing_Expiration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {

        db,err := sql.Open("DB_Connect")

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            println(err)
        }



        var result string

        errr := db.QueryRow("select json_build_object('Expiration', array_to_json(array_agg(t))) from (select fullname,ad_end from profiles where id=32)t").Scan(&result)


        defer db.Close()
        switch {
        case errr != nil:
            log.Fatal(errr)


        }


        fmt.Fprintf(w,result)

}
```

The above method works correctly and the data is returned to the browser then I try to make this method async

```
 func Listing_Expiration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
        go func(){

            db,err := sql.Open("DB_Connect")

            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                println(err)
            }



            var result string

            errr := db.QueryRow("select json_build_object('Expiration', array_to_json(array_agg(t))) from (select fullname,ad_end from profiles where id=32)t").Scan(&result)


            defer db.Close()
            switch {
            case errr != nil:
                log.Fatal(errr)


            }


            fmt.Fprintf(w,result)

        }()
    }
```

The async above returns nothing the only thing I have changed is that I added the **Go func()** inside the method so that it is async and everything else is the same . I checked and the database is returning the same content back just have no idea why the async is not printing the results back to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The net/http server completes the response when the handler returns. Anything written to the response after the handler returns is ignored.

The handler function `Listing_Expiration` is returning before the anonymous function executes `fmt.Fprintf(w,result)`.

To fix this, use a [sync.WaitGroup](http://godoc.org/sync#WaitGroup):

```
func Listing_Expiration(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
  var wg sync.WaitGroup
  wg.Add(1)
  go func(){
    defer wg.Done()
    // same code here as in question
  }()
  wg.Wait()
}
```

The net/http server starts a goroutine for each connection and runs handlers in those goroutines. If the code in the question is the complete handler, then there's no reason to start yet another goroutine.

Comment: Perfect that worked, I'm going to read the docs now, so basically whenever I use a GoRoutine that prints to the browser then always use WaitGoup right ?

Comment: If the application writes to the response from a goroutine, then the application must do something to ensure that the handler waits for the goroutine. WaitGroups are a convenient way to do this. Channels can also be used.  To avoid races on the response writer, it's usually best to write to the response from the handler's goroutine.  It's not an issue in this example, but consider what happens if app runs two queries async.

Comment: Thanks a lot that explains it perfectly I will rewrite the response from the Goroutine handler now.